# Nodejs run promises sequentially

Tags: node.js, express, promise

Dears ,

How can i run promises in nodejs sequentially , in the following example am looping through array of hours then for each fetched hour get result from the database , the issue here : am getting results but i want it sequentially same order that i got hours .

```
angular.forEach(SharedVar.getCategories(), function (h) {
                                        t = h.split('-', 2);
                                        t = t[0];
                                        RESTApi.getAnswerdCallsByHour(t).then(function (answerdTotal) {
                                                $scope.answerdCallsTotalByHour.push(answerdTotal);
                                                var d = SharedVar.getDataS();
                                                d[count] = answerdTotal;
                                                SharedVar.setDataS(d);

                                                count++;

                                        });

                                });
```

Thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it sequently would be to do one Request and do the next request inside the promise.

I think the better approach by far is to extend your SharedVar.setDataS(d) function in a way, that it does not depend on getting the data sequentially. Like having a SharedVar.setDataS(d, index) and using the config var in your $http.get (or whatever) functioncall inside your RESTApi to promote that index all the way to the promise.

If your RESTApi looks like this:

```
var RESTApi = {
  getAnswerdCallsByHour : function(hour) {
    var url = "bla.com/myservice?hour=" + hour;
    return $http.get(url).data;
  }
  // Some other Methods...
```

Then you need a way to pass something to "reorder" your Data when it arrives asynchronously, this could be a index you count up or in your case maybe the hour Variable:

```
  var RESTApi = {
  getAnswerdCallsByHour : function(hour) {
    var url = "bla.com/myservice?hour=" + hour;
    var config = [];
    config.hour = hour;
    return $http.get(url, config); // Return the promise not just data or a specific field
  }
  // Some other Methods...
```

Now when your promise is fullfiled you can access your "hour" Variable like so:

```
var d = SharedVar.getDataS();
d[promise.config.hour] = promise.data;
SharedVar.setDataS(d);
```

Now you know what piece of data correlates to which request and you do not need to recieve Data in order. The last piece only works properly when hours runs sequential from 0 to 23, if that isn't the case you need to:

```
  var RESTApi = {
  getAnswerdCallsByHour : function(hour, index) {
    var url = "bla.com/myservice?hour=" + hour;
    var config = [];
    config.index = index;
    return $http.get(url, config);
  }
  // Some other Methods...
  ...
  ...
  var d = SharedVar.getDataS();
  d[promise.config.index] = promise.data;
  SharedVar.setDataS(d);
```

Comment: i have tried your suggest , still facing same issue . what i did is passing index to SharedVar.setData(d,index) . about RESTApi am just fetching data from database and return count .

Comment: Yeah, not exactly shure if you got what i was trying to say. I added some code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var promise = Promise.resolve(); // make an empty promise in the way you do it with your promise library
angular.forEach(SharedVar.getCategories(), function (h) {

   promise.then(function() {
       return RESTApi.getAnswerdCallsByHour(t).then(function (answerdTotal) {});
   });

});
```

Comment: Still having same issue with your solution . every time i run the app am getting results not in order .

Answer (score 0):

Safari's answer is how I typically handle this. (Sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment yet...) You were experiencing problems with it because the example provided does not capture and use the new promise in subsequent loops. See my comments on the slightly modified version here:

```
    var promise = Promise.resolve();
    angular.forEach(SharedVar.getCategories(), function (h) {
        t = h.split('-', 2);
        t = t[0];

        // You must capture the new promise here; the next loop will wait
        // for the promise returned from getAnswerdCallsByHour to resolve.
        promise = promise.then(function() {
            // Halt downstream promises until this returned promises finishes
            return RESTApi.getAnswerdCallsByHour(t).then(function (answerdTotal) {
                $scope.answerdCallsTotalByHour.push(answerdTotal);
                var d = SharedVar.getDataS();
                d[count] = answerdTotal;
                SharedVar.setDataS(d);

                count++;
            });
        });
    });
```